# Video not playing despite being able to play through (javascript)

Tags: javascript, video, aframe

I'm making a VR web app using A-Frame.
I have all my videos un a array (video[ID] = URL).
OnLoad I go through my video array to create my video tags and add them to the page (vie a LoadAssets() function). I also use Promises to make sure I can play through all the videos before leaving the "loading" scene and opening up the main menu.

```
function LoadAssets(){

    const LoadingPromises = new Array();

    for(let vID in video){
        let video_asset = document.createElement('video');
            video_asset.setAttribute('id', vID);
            video_asset.setAttribute('preload', true);
            video_asset.setAttribute('playsinline', true);
            video_asset.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', true);
            video_asset.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
            video_asset.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');
            video_asset.setAttribute('src', video[vID]);
        document.getElementById('assets').appendChild(video_asset); //add the video tag to the 'a-assets' tag for a-frame
        
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            video_asset.oncanplaythrough = resolve();
            video_asset.onerror = reject;
        });
        LoadingPromises.push(promise);
    }

    return Promise.all(LoadingPromises)
        .then(() => { //bring up the main menu })
        .catch(error => { console.error('Error loading resources:', error);});
}
```

But, when I click on the desired VR element to play the video, the video returns a "ready state" of 1.

```
function PlayVideo(what){

    var Player = document.getElementById("Player");
    var Source = what.dataset.vid;// the ID of the video to play

        Player.setAttribute('src',Source);
        Player.addEventListener('materialtextureloaded', function(){ Player.components.material.material.map.image.play(); } //only actually plays the video if loaded
    var Video = document.querySelector(Source);
        //I added check if the video was playing (with "playing" defined as 'this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2'
        window.setTimeout(function(){     
            if(Video.playing){
                //show player            
            }
            else{ throw Video.id+" is not playing (Ready State: "+Video.readyState+")"; PlayVideo(what); }
        }, 1000);
}
```

The video is rather large but the Web app is supposed to run on a local server and be experienced with an oculus quest 2. On PC it works fine and it's not always the same video that won't play. How can I make sure the video is fully ready / loaded before playing?